# GPO's filtered out - wrong domain name reported by BGinfo

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rename, windows, group-policy

I am trying to locate a group policy deployment issue I have.

The problem is that domain related GPO's are filtered out. We renamed our domain lately from: **CONTOSO** to: `lan.CONTOSO.com` (Netbios name is: `CONTOSO` and unchanged).

I started to investigate, and the first sign of problem is when running BGinfo - we still see in the **LOGON DOMAIN** and **MACHINE DOMAIN**: `CONTOSO` and not what I would think I want to see: **lan.CONTOSO.com**

If I run : GPresult, the domain I see is: lan.CONTOSO.com (as well as correct DC, OU values)

- This error is all over the computers (including the DC)

So: what should I see in the BGinfo report? and how to fix it, if it's wrong.

EDIT:

Here are : gpresult /h results

```
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1981-2001
Created On 24/11/2014 at 11:37:00 AM

RSOP data for CONTOSSO\user.admin on LTLVADMIN1407 : Logging Mode
---------------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  6.1.7601
Site Name:                   SiteIL
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\user.admin
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
CN=LTLVADMIN1407,OU=Laptops,OU=Default,OU=CONTOSSO_Computers,DC=lan,DC=CONTOSSO,DC=com
Last time Group Policy was applied: 24/11/2014 at 10:06:21 AM
Group Policy was applied from:      DC3.lan.CONTOSSO.com
Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
Domain Name:                        CONTOSSO
Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Default Domain Policy
    SpiceWorks Firewall
    Firewall - Disabled
    Printers
    Sophos Tasks Enabler
    Logon - Enable Verbose State
    WSUS - Default

The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Local Group Policy
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

The computer is a part of the following security groups
-------------------------------------------------------
    BUILTIN\Administrators
    Everyone
    SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$LTLVADMIN1407
    SophosUser
    BUILTIN\Users
    NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    LTLVADMIN1407$
    System Mandatory Level


USER SETTINGS1
--------------
CN=ADMIN User,OU=IT_Department,OU=CONTOSSO_Users,DC=lan,DC=CONTOSSO,DC=com
Last time Group Policy was applied: 24/11/2014 at 11:05:04 AM
Group Policy was applied from:      DC3.lan.CONTOSSO.com
Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
Domain Name:                        CONTOSSO
Domain Type:                        Windows 2000

Applied Group Policy Objects
-----------------------------
    Default Domain Policy
    Drive Mappings
    Printers

The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    SpiceWorks Firewall
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    Local Group Policy
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    Sophos Tasks Enabler
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    Logon - Enable Verbose State
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    Firewall - Disabled
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    WSUS - Default
        Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

The user is a part of the following security groups
---------------------------------------------------
    Everyone
    HelpLibraryUpdaters
    SophosUser
    SophosAdministrator
    BUILTIN\Users
    BUILTIN\Administrators
    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
    CONSOLE LOGON
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    This Organization
    LOCAL
    High Mandatory Level
```

Here is the UserDnsDomain on computer

```
C:\Users\user.admin>echo %UserDnsDomain%+
LAN.CONTOSO.COM+
```

The GPO I refer to is not even shown in the list: It's a logon script, which is a user configuration value.

[image]

[image]

GPO Info

[image]

**Group policy Modelling**

I think here lies the problem, my username is defined as: `CONTOSSO\user` 
and user container as: lan.contoso.com\contoso_users.
The GPO I need is not shown either.

[image]

Problem lies maybe in the Netbios name? Cached value ?

[image]

Comment: Four of your questions are now related to this domain rename - I certainly hope this stands as an example to you and others that a domain rename is a dangerous and complicated task which is rarely worth it.

Comment: Believe me. I aint gonna do another rename  in the near future. 

Comment: Anyway, to help fix this issue we're going to need more details. How do you know they're being filtered out - what does GPResult /r actuallt say exactly? Can you create a new GPO, does that work?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the variable USERDNSDOMAIN?

Comment: This is a guess, but those GPO's are being filtered because they're empty. Additionally, the names look very "Computer Policy" to me. Are you sure they have anything in the user settings? And you've definitely not switched them to "User Policy Only"

Comment: If the GPO isn't shown in that list then it's not been filtered - it's not even attempting to process it. Are you sure it's linked to the correct OU etc? What does Group Policy *Modelling* show? *Should* it apply?

Comment: What you've shown isn't modelling - you've done another GPResult

Comment: I'm not convinced this anything to do with your rename at all - feels like a Group Policy config issue. Start from scratch and make sure this GPO is configured and linked correctly

Comment: And why are you enforcing all your GPO's - this is a pet hate of mine, because I suspect it doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the GPO to the **Domain** as well.

Drag your GPO to the Domain you want it to apply (ads that to the "Location")

[image]